# How can I get the parameters of an Entity Framework query?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

If I create a query of `IQueryable<T>`, I can call .ToString() to get the SQL that will be called, but that SQL may contain parameters like @p__linq__0, @p__linq__1, etc. Is there a way to get those parameters and their values from the `IQueryable<T>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's frustratingly complicated, in my experience, but this code got me there:

```
        var dbQuery = (DbQuery<T>)query;
        // get the IInternalQuery internal variable from the DbQuery object
        var iqProp = dbQuery.GetType().GetProperty("InternalQuery", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        var iq = iqProp.GetValue(dbQuery, null);
        // get the ObjectQuery internal variable from the IInternalQuery object
        var oqProp = iq.GetType().GetProperty("ObjectQuery", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        var objectQuery = (ObjectQuery<T>)oqProp.GetValue(iq, null);

        var sqlString = objectQuery.ToTraceString(); // this will populate the parameters collection
        foreach (var objectParam in objectQuery.Parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{objectParam.Name} = {objectParam.Value.ToString()}");
        }
```

Note that this code only works for `IQueryable<T>` objects that are actually `DbQuery<T>`, as are created by entity framework. If you intend to wrap this in a utility method, some type checking may be in order.

Comment: This seems to only work if I step through the code slowly. Otherwise the `Parameters` property is empty. Is there something I can do to guarantee that the Parameters will be populated?

Comment: I think I got it now. I had to call ToString on my query first. It must only parse/populate stuff once that's called.