# Searching a DateTime using a search string in Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I have an MVC project which outputs a nullable DateTime (`DateTime?`) as a string to the user for each model item as shown below (my user interface has paging so I only do this computation for a small number of records - in other words, this part is okay):

```
foreach (DocumentEvent item in Model.items)
    @(item?.TimeUtc?.ToString() ?? "N/A")
```

I want to add a search functionality. I've tried searching as follows, but this is not performant because `AsEnumerable` materializes my list and I am now in the C# world, enumerating through each record:

```
using (var context = new ClientEventsContext())
    var items = context.Events.AsEnumerable().Where(x => {
        (x?.TimeUtc?.ToString() ?? "N/A").Contains(model.search)
    });
```

Instead I want to take advantage of my SQL Server database. How can I build an SQL Server-friendly query for the above code without `AsEnumerable` that will produce the same results as my current logic?

Comment: Just take off the AsEnumerable and perform the query at the IQueryable level

Comment: @Fals You can't, it will raise exceptions because Entity Framework can't translate `(x?.TimeUtc?.ToString() ?? "N/A").Contains(model.search)` into an SQL query.

Comment: Generally, one uses a range search for querying dates and times, and leaves them in their native data format.  A `Contains` string search is going to be fairly useless.  I might search for `'0'` or `'/'`.

Comment: @MattJohnson That's exactly what I want to support, searching for `0` or `/`, if possible...pretty much, searching for any parts of what the `DateTime` may contain as displayed to the user. You bring up a good point that maybe the approach is wrong, maybe I should add a DB column to store the string representation of the `DateTime` as displayed to the user, and then query that.

Comment: @Alexandru Wich version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: *I want to take advantage of my SQL Server database* -- keep in mind that you kill any index by transforming a database value before filtering.

Comment: @GertArnold Its not indexed, but good point.

Comment: @Alexandru - Sorry, but I cannot imagine that would be a valid use case.  Consider dates may be represented differently (`yyyy-mm-dd` vs `mm/dd/yyyy` vs `dd/mm/yyyy`, etc.).  Also, if there are times involved, it may be unlikely that someone would enter an exact match at the same precision that the values are stored in.  In general, it's a best practice to always store dates and times using the best native data type (`date`, `time`, `datetime2`, `datetimeoffset`, etc.), not as strings.

Comment: @MattJohnson When you say to consider dates being represented differently, are you referring to inside the database or inside the web server, because those should both ultimately be tied down to a set format in this situation.

Comment: They should be treated as dates and times, not as strings.  In C# code, as `DateTime` or a `DateTimeOffset`.  In SQL code, as `datetime2` (or one of the other types depending on your needs).  In these native types, there is no format.  Formatting only applies for string representation for display or input to/from the user (or to you, the developer, during debugging, etc.).  Think of it this way - do you pass money values around as `"$1,000.00"`?  NO, you pass a decimal of `1000.0`.  Formatting is a *secondary* concern.

Comment: @MattJohnson This is more about the user experience from my POV, but to each their own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you can build and use LINQ to Entities compatible conversion from date to string in `M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt` format. Rather that embedding that monster inside the query, I will use a custom "marker" method and will bind the implementation using `ExpressionVisitor`. This way you can experiment and change the format if needed (even add some controlling arguments) w/o affecting the readability of the query.

First, the implementation:

```
public static class EFExtensions
{
    public static string ToCustomDateFormat(this DateTime value)
    {
        // Should never happen
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> ApplyCustomDateFormat<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        var expression = new CustomDateFormatBinder().Visit(source.Expression);
        if (source.Expression == expression) return source;
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
    }

    class CustomDateFormatBinder : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(EFExtensions) && node.Method.Name == "ToCustomDateFormat")
            {
                var date = Visit(node.Arguments[0]);
                var year = DatePart(date, v => DbFunctions.Right("0000" + v.Year, 4));
                var month = DatePart(date, v => v.Month.ToString());
                var day = DatePart(date, v => v.Day.ToString());
                var hour = DatePart(date, v => (1 + (v.Hour + 11) % 12).ToString());
                var minute = DatePart(date, v => DbFunctions.Right("0" + v.Minute, 2));
                var second = DatePart(date, v => DbFunctions.Right("0" + v.Second, 2));
                var amPM = DatePart(date, v => v.Hour < 12 ? "AM" : "PM");
                var dateSeparator = Expression.Constant("/");
                var timeSeparator = Expression.Constant(":");
                var space = Expression.Constant(" ");
                var result = Expression.Call(
                    typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new Type[] { typeof(string[]) }),
                    Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(string),
                        month, dateSeparator, day, dateSeparator, year, space,
                        hour, timeSeparator, minute, timeSeparator, second, space, amPM));
                return result;    
            }
            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }

        Expression DatePart(Expression date, Expression<Func<DateTime, string>> part)
        {
            var parameter = part.Parameters[0];
            parameterMap.Add(parameter, date);
            var body = Visit(part.Body);
            parameterMap.Remove(parameter);
            return body;
        }

        Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> parameterMap = new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression>();

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            Expression replacement;
            return parameterMap.TryGetValue(node, out replacement) ? replacement : node;
        }
    }
}
```

then the usage:

```
var items = context.Events
    .Where(x => x.TimeUtc != null && 
        x.TimeUtc.Value.ToCustomDateFormat().Contains(model.search))
    .ApplyCustomDateFormat();
```

Comment: This is such beautiful code. I wish I could give you more points.

Comment: You are welcome mate :) Your words worth much more than some virtual points!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. This syntax seems to work:

```
using (var context = new ClientEventsContext())
    var items = context.Events.Where(x => {
        x.TimeUtc.HasValue && x.TimeUtc.Value.ToString().Contains(model.search)
    });
```

Comment: but you are using AsEnumerable in that solution. I think that after EF 6.1 you can use ToString() in a query.

Comment: @yosoy Sorry, I forgot to remove it when I copied and pasted it from the question, it works without it is the point. Edited the answer.

Comment: Even this answer has some annoying issues at the moment. For example, if I see this timestamp, `3/19/2012 7:22:00 AM`, search works for `2012` or `7:22`, but fails for `3/19/2012` and fails for `7:22:00`...it must be using the SQL Server DateTime formatting or something...so, maybe, I need to find a way to edit my answer to format it the same way, or a better approach.

Comment: Right now I can't seem to figure out how to get the DB's exact query-friendly format.

Comment: Do you know the format of the search string and the culture?

Comment: @IvanStoev `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is `{en-US}`

Comment: @IvanStoev I have tried a bunch of different formats for the search string, like `2012-03` or `2012/03` or even different permutations of these in case month and day are mixed up.

Comment: I need to check when I have some more time the actual parameters this passes up for the query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015157/how-can-i-get-the-parameters-of-an-entity-framework-query

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using [SqlFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466188.aspx) library to convert anything to Raw Query and do the job at SQL level, for example:

```
using (var context = new ClientEventsContext())
var items = context.Events.Where(x =>
    SqlFunctions.PatIndex(model.search, 
    SqlFunctions.DateName('your pattern here', x?.TimeUtc) ?? "N/A").Value > -1
);
```

Comment: `StringConvert` seems to take only a `double` or a `decimal` though?

Comment: @Alexandru There's a overload for each primitive.

Comment: Not for `DateTime?` though as far as I can tell. See for yourself if you don't believe me: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions_methods(v=vs.110).aspx There is `Checksum` but I am not sure how to use it. Something might be off with the method you are trying to call.

Comment: @Alexandru Sure.. your are right, then you should user DateName my bad

Comment: @Alexandru You are right. Your solution is better because `ToString` is supported for every primitive type, and also the solution is not bound to SqlServer. `StringConvert` is mainly for limited number formatting with decimals.

Comment: @IvanStoev But even mine has issues, for example, if I see this timestamp, `3/19/2012 7:22:00 AM`, search works for `2012` or `7:22`, but fails for `3/19/2012` and fails for `7:22:00`...it must be using the SQL Server DateTime formatting or something...so, maybe, I need to find a way to edit my answer to format it the same way, or a better approach.

Comment: @Alexandru Yeah, that's the drawback. Simulating exactly your UI formatting when searching in the database is not easy :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Yeah but right now I can't seem to figure out how to get the DB's exact query-friendly format.