# Extracting parameters from an Entity Framework Core query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to migrate from Entity Framework 6 to Entity Framework Core. In one of my scenarios I need to extract parameters from an Entity Framework `IQueryable` object. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015157/how-can-i-get-the-parameters-of-an-entity-framework-query) describes how it can be done in Entity Framework 6.

Is it possible to do something similar in Entity Framework Core?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good way to do this in EF Core. Why would you even want to do it though?

Comment: It was rather a terrible hack, which worked in EF 6, allowing me to execute an aggregation query in more efficient way. It looks like I have to do it in some other way.

Comment: EF Core query processing pipeline is quite different from EF6. Post another question with the actual case and we'll be happy to help (if we can of course).